# Is there any way to set dynamically index of array in batch script

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

Is there any way to set dyanamically index of array in batch script. 
please check my script bellow.

```
@echo off

SET /A i = 0
echo %i%   
set fileList[%i%]="1.txt"

Set /A i+=1
echo %i%
set fileList[%i%]="2.txt"

Set /A i+=1
echo %i%
set fileList[%i%]="3.txt"
```

Comment: `FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,3) DO set "fileList[%%G]=%%G.txt"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set index of array dynamically as mentioned in question & to check if it sets a incremented value for variable i & printed its index.

This code is absolutely fine, when I looped through the array I see all values set at its index, however `echo %i%` does not show actual value.

Anyway it is resolved now. Thanks for your help.